# How to map through a responses from an API in react

Tags: reactjs

I did fetch data from the NYTimes API and console log the response in the browser. I have done this by writing a function do_search. How can I send the responses as a prop to another component?

Here is a response form the API.
 [image]

Here is my code for INDEX.JS. Please notice that I want to pass the prop in Listview component which is at 6th line from the last.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SearchComponent from "./components/Search_component";
import ListViewComponent from "./components/Listview_component";
import _ from "lodash";
const axios = require("axios");
const api_key = "my_api_key";
let url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            q: " "
        };
        this.do_search("Bangladesh");
        this.do_search = this.do_search.bind(this);
    }

    do_search(keyword) {
        axios
            .get(
                url, // takes the variable url
                {
                    params: {
                        api_key: api_key,
                        q: keyword
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const search_throttle = _.debounce(keyword => {
            this.do_search(keyword);
        }, 500);

        return (
            <div>
                <SearchComponent
                    searchkeyword={
                        search_throttle
                    }
                />
                <ListViewComponent data={this.do_search.response.docs} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the response to a state and pass this state as a prop.

```
this.state = {
            q: " ",
            searchResponse :null,
        };
  ........

       do_search = (keyword) =>{
        axios
            .get(...)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({searchResponse:response.data});
            })
.........
                <ListViewComponent data={this.state.searchResponse} />
            </div>
```

Now when ever the state value gets its response from api, render is called again and listview gets the value.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: Thats because u r not getting 'this' change the function declaration as, do_search = (keyword) =>{

Comment: i dont understand. can you please explain ?

Comment: Did you change the code as mentioned in the edited answer?

Comment: If I use this.state = {
            q: " ",
            searchResponse :null,
        };
then it shows me this error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null**

if I set searchResponse = [ ] then it does not show any error but also does not map any data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178694/discussion-between-shojib-mahabub-and-rohith-murali).

Answer (score 0):

Make an array where you will push response.data from then method in axios. Pass that array as prop to ListView component.

Inside ListView component make some loader that will show to the user that component is fetching data. When data arrives, show what you got from NYTimes API

Comment: I have set the sate from then method. this is showing this error 
https://pastebin.com/BP0NsUyP

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'setState' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when your state changes, views are re-rendered with props updated

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SearchComponent from "./components/Search_component";
import ListViewComponent from "./components/Listview_component";
import _ from "lodash";
const axios = require("axios");
const api_key = "9f4cd2e5a8884f3eb5853436e74be7e6";
let url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            q: " "
        };
        this.do_search("Bangladesh");
        this.do_search = this.do_search.bind(this);
    }

    do_search(keyword) {
        axios
            .get(
                url, // takes the variable url
                {
                    params: {
                        api_key: api_key,
                        q: keyword
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({ response }); // SET STATE HERE
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const search_throttle = _.debounce(keyword => {
            this.do_search(keyword);
        }, 500);

        return (
            <div>
                <SearchComponent
                    searchkeyword={
                        search_throttle
                    }
                />
                <ListViewComponent data={this.state.response} /> // GET STATE HERE
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```